# Can't load another level

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was following an online tutorial to make [this little game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHwYs.png) in Unity and when I got to the end, I wound up with two different levels. The only problem is that I can only play one of them. I tried adding it in the build settings but for some reason, it just isn't working. Maybe there's a problem with the code? I don't know. This is my first-ever working with Unity so I'm still figuring things out.

```cs
public class LevelControllerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static int _nextLevelIndex = 1;
    private NewBehaviourScript1[] _enemies;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _enemies = FindObjectsOfType<NewBehaviourScript1>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach(NewBehaviourScript1 NewBehaviourScript1 in _enemies)
        {
            if (NewBehaviourScript1 != null)
                return;
        }

        Debug.Log("You killed all enemies!");

        _nextLevelIndex++;
        string nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextLevelName);
    }
}
```

Comment: "leveltwo" and "Level2" are not the same name.

Answer (score 1):

```
string nextLevelName = "Level" + _nextLevelIndex;
```

This line of code makes the string `nextLevelName` something like `Level1`, or `Level2`, however, you are trying to match up to the string `leveltwo`.

To fix this you need to match up the strings, I believe you can just change the scene `leveltwo` to `Level2` (and change all of the other scenes accordingly).